# System Configuration Error: ImageRouteHandler does not implement IHttpHandlerFactory or IHttpHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, handler

I use asp.net c# 4.

I have a class used for ImageRouteHandler.

Images are processed (so I can display in my system), but in my logs I receive this message:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
WebProject.Cms.BusinessLogics.SEO.Routing.ImageRouteHandler does not implement IHttpHandlerFactory or IHttpHandler.

System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: WebProject.Cms.BusinessLogics.SEO.Routing.ImageRouteHandler does not implement IHttpHandlerFactory or IHttpHandler.
   at System.Web.Configuration.HandlerFactoryCache.GetHandlerType(String type)
   at System.Web.Configuration.HandlerFactoryCache..ctor(String type)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.GetFactory(String type)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

---

Initial part of my Class (I think the error is in this part)

```
public class ImageRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{

    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        ..........
```

Do you have any idea what is wrong? Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you stated what the issue was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think instead the problem resides in your web.config not in the class.

Try to inspect it where you define your handler.